# C Programming fprintf issue

Tags: c, printf

I have a problem when writing a file on the text. As you could see, I used `\n` to put another set of my data on the next line. The problem is when i close the file and save again the data per line which ends with `\n` becomes `\n\n` and so on. That's why my file looks like this

FIRST SAVE

```
 test, test, test
 test, test, test
```

SECOND SAVE

```
 test, test, test

 test, test, test
```

THIRD SAVE

```
test, test, test


test, test, test
```

that's why when i display it on the screen... there are garbage value in between... My code is as follows:

```
save(){
     int i = 0;
     FILE *stream = NULL;
     stream = fopen("student.txt", "wt");
     printf("\nSaving the student list directory. Wait a moment please...");
     printf("\nExiting the program...");
     for (i=0; i<recordCtr; i++){
        fprintf(stream, "%s, %s, %s\n", array[i]->studentID, array[i]->name, array[i]->course);  
     }                   
}
```

Help please... any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is in `array[i]->course`?  Does it have a newline at its end?  What is in `array[i]->studentID`?  Does it have a newline at its beginning?

Comment: It's very possible that your `array[i]->course` has another newline terminator. Hint: `fgets()` reads the whole line together with the newline terminator. How exactly are you "resaving" the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure of what you exactly do but if you parse back the file before saving it again probably you are forgetting to remove the old `\n` from the original last string..

EDIT: this is actually right. The OP uses `fgets`function, which includes the line terminator.

So starting from "test, test, test\n" with `strtok` he will obtain "test" "test" "test\n" so that when it will be saved back a new newline (forget it) is added to the file.

You could fix it by setting last character to null with

```
linebuffer[strlen(linebuffer)-2] = '\0'
```

(it is safe since fgets return a null-terminated string by itself)

You can also add `\n` to delimiters used, you should end up with same behavior (not sure about empty tokens with strtok but IIRC they are just discarded).

Comment: He already acknowledges this - 'The problem is when i close the file and save again the file \n becomes \n\n and so on.'

Comment: @DMan: and how do you think he's doing that?

Comment: @Jack why did you changed it from linebuffer[strlen(linebuffer)-1] = '\0' to linebuffer[strlen(linebuffer)-2] = '\0'. Can you please explain.. thank you.

Comment: 1) `strlen-1` has to be dropped, 2) what about `""`?`

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing this is on windows -- change your line:

```
stream = fopen("student.txt", "wt");
```

to:

```
stream = fopen("student.txt", "wb");
```

And you won't get extra `\r`s.

Alternatively, maybe the last of the strings you're `fprintf`ing already has a newline at the end.

Comment: It's not because of modifiers.

Comment: stream = fopen("student.txt", "wb"); doesn't help.. what to do?

Answer (score 3):

I'd guess that your `array[i]->course` field contains the \n previously written in the last save. Check the code that populates the array and make sure it is skipping newline characters.

Comment: how can i make sure that it skips newline characters??? is there a function for that or i need to write it on my own?

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
fgets(linebuffer, 45, stream);
```

remove the trailing `\n` from `linebuffer` if there is one:

```
for (int i=strlen(linebuff)-1; i>=0 && linebuff[i]=='\n'; linebuff[i--]='\0');
```